# Background Color and Border Radius property not working together in React Native - Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styling

It happened after updating my react native project to 0.61.1 from 0.59.9. I have `TouchableOpacity` with borderRadius and backgroundColor style When I look into the iOS it looks good but in Android, there is no background color in the view. It is just transparent. Previously, there was no such issue.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: 'black' ,justifyContent: 'center', flex:1, borderRadius: scale(22)}} />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is scale() a custom function returning a value? I have tried it this way though and it works;

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: 'black' ,justifyContent: 'center', flex:1, borderRadius: 22}}>
  <Text>Sign In</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Or else try to clear caches: `npm clear cache --force`